# What's the difference between local and global basis functions in a regression?

Tags: machine-learning, regression

For a regression with some basis functions, I read that gaussian basis functions are local whereas polynomial basis functions are global. What does it mean ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

A gaussian is centered around a certain value and tapers off to 0 as you get far away from it. In contrast, a polynomial extends over the whole range.

This means that a gaussian will model a local feature of the data (like a bump or valley), whereas a polynomial will model global patterns in the data (say, an overall downward or upward trend).

Answer (score 3):

A local basis function (you will also often see referred to as *compactly supported basis function*) is essentially non-zero only on a particular interval. Examples of such functions used in approximation / regression are B-Splines, wavelets etc. Polynomials on the other hand, are non-zero everywhere apart from at their roots. Consider a least squares regression curve using monomial basis - your resulting vandermonde matrix will not exhibit any kind of structure - an element can only be zero if x=0. Now assume that you try the same problem with a BSpline curve with fixed knots. Now because of the fact that the basis functions are local, your matrix will be banded - each row will contain zero items because the effect of the basis function is only present on a certain interval.